# Transition twice with one target (CSS3)

Tags: css, transition, target, css-transitions

I'm trying to animate a kind of slide show using CSS3 and its "transition" and "target" functionalities.

Thus far I have this: http://dk8.co/slide.html

Using the CSS:

```
[id*=thumbs] {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

[id*=thumbs]:target {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}

#body {
    position:relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:200px; left:200px;width:600px;">
<p align="center"><a href="#thumbs">up</a>
<div id="body">
<table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="5" id="thumbs">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="" width="100%" height="160"  /></td>
    <td><img src="" width="100%" height="160"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="" width="100%" height="160"  /></td>
    <td><img src="" width="100%" height="160"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="" width="100%" height="160"  /></td>
    <td><img src="" width="100%" height="160"  /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="" width="100%" height="160"  /></td>
    <td><img src="" width="100%" height="160"  /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

However, I can only get the transition to occur once. I want to be able to click on "up" again and get it to move up some more. Is there any way this can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not possible in CSS, are you willing to include a bit of JS?

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely include some JS if that would work...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example using translate instead. It achieves what you want to do without any javascript.

Have a look at: http://www.designmadeingermany.de/slideshow/

Browse the source code, its cristal clear.